# Is there a JavaScript technique to check for type equality in >,<,>=,<= operations?

Tags: javascript, lint

If I have `if(Object.keys(obj) < 2)` then I have a bug that might slip past my tests if I don't test it with objects with property counts below and at/above 2. i.e. it should have `.length`.

If my linter were to check for type on either side of <,>,<=,>= then it could warn about this.

Alternatively, how else could you catch this? I already know that more high quality tests would catch this. The problem with that is you never know when you have enough high quality tests. If a linter or other tool had the ability to warn of types in this situation then this would be automatically caught.

Comment: You might try [ESLint](http://eslint.org/docs/developer-guide/working-with-rules.html) which seems to be pretty configurable, but there might be a steep learning curve to get what you want.

Comment: There is no conclusive way to check for type equality in a linter without actually running the code because the code can do all sorts of things and a linter can't know what might actually be present in a variable when it is used in a comparison. This is a consequence of using a language such as Javascript that does not require strict typing. There are variants of Javascript such as TypeScript (that can be compiled to Javascript) that offer more capabilities in this regard.

Comment: Type inferencing is very complicated -- as far as I'm aware no JS linter does this though it might be possible to do so in (very) limited circumstances.

Comment: That's in regards to plain JavaScript -- TypeScript (as jfriend00 mentioned) does detect this scenario with its stricter rules on types.  Here's an example to test out: [TypeScript playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=if%20%28Object.keys%28[]%29%20<%202%29%20alert%281%29%3B). You'll see that there's a red line underneath the condition.

Comment: TypeScript is not a bad idea. In fact I wrote a blog post about improving code quality using TypeScript a couple of years ago http://www.guyellisrocks.com/2013/07/typescript-as-better-jslint.html and the reason that I have never followed my own advice in this respect is because it's been difficult to add TypeScript to the tooling chain as a type-inference-checker. Thank you for reminding me about my own advice to others. I feel like somewhat of a hypocrite for forgetting about it. :)

Comment: @jfriend00 I'll accept that TypeScript suggestion as an answer to this question if you want to answer the question with it. It achieves the goal that the question set out to address. It still needs to be "tooled" but it's the best solution I can think of. The question is bad as it assumes that a linter is the answer - I'll try and reword it.

Comment: Thanks @Qantas94Heavy for that snippet. That error is exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no conclusive way to check for type equality in a linter without actually running the code because the code can do all sorts of things and a linter can't know what might actually be present in a variable when it is used in a comparison. This is a consequence of using a language such as Javascript that does not require strict typing.

There are variants of Javascript such as TypeScript (that can be compiled to Javascript) that offer more capabilities in this regard.